# Lazy Hibernate Initialization No Session, Could not initialize Proxy

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am creating a e-prescribing module will allow several orders to be created and added to a list before being confirmed (saved in DB at once together). I have two forms - One where the order is created and the second with a link to add more orders, where the submit button will store all the orders (ArrayList items) in the DB. i.e. Each order upon creation gets added to an ArrayList [createNewDrugOrder() method below]

When I try to save each order inside this method - it works fine. but my requirement is to have the facility to store the orders as a draft before confirming them (storing in DB).

```
    public class DrugordersPageController{

     SessionFactory sessionfactory;

     public void controller(){
      if ("addDraftOrder".equals(action)){
       createNewDrugOrder();
      }
      if ("confirmOrder".equals(action)){
       saveOrder();
      }
     }

     createNewDrugOrder(){
      DrugOrder order = new DrugOrder();
      order.setDose(1);
      order.setDuration(1);
      order.setQuantity(1);
      ConfirmOrderClass.orderToConfirm.add(order);
     }

     saveOrder(){
      DrugOrder order = ConfirmOrderClass.getDrugOrderMain();
      order = (DrugOrder) Context.getOrderService().saveOrder(order, null); //Here is where error is thrown
     }
    }


    class ConfirmOrderClass{

     public static ArrayList<DrugOrder> orderToConfirm = new ArrayList<DrugOrder>();

     public static ArrayList<DrugOrder> getDrugOrderMain(){
      return orderToConfirm;
     }
    }
```

I understand this is a case of object being detached from the session, but I am unable to get it fixed. Calling session.save or session.update in the second form doesn't help..Neither does Hibernate.initialize(object) or adding a @Transactional notation

when I call Session s = sessionfactory.getCurrentSession or openSession, i still get null pointer error. Although I am able to retrieve the values of order.getDose(), order.getDuration() etc..
Please help!